# recursive find number in between in C

Tags: c, algorithm, function, recursion, range

I want to find the number within a range in an array and must be in a recursive way. The function variables couldn't be modified.

Let's say in the range of 2 and 3

The input is : `int a[] = {4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2};`

and the output will be `= {3,3,2}` , 3 found

Not sure how to code the recursive function in this case. The below I have tried not working.

```
int within(int a[], int N, int lower, int upper, int result[])
{
 if(N == 1 && N <= upper && N>= lower) 
    return a[0];

 return within(&a[1], N-1, lower, upper, result);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2};
    int result[6] = {0};
    int i, nResult;

    nResult = within(a, 6, 2, 3, result);

    printf("%d data passed the bounds\n", nResult);
    for (i = 0; i < nResult; i++){
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a recursive function?

Comment: can you define `N` - is it the number of elements of `a` - why are you checking the value of `N` - looks like you should be querying the value of `a[i]`

Comment: You never assign anything to the result array; you send the same array element in every recursive call; `N` doesn't appear to be relevant at all. You might want to go back to the book.

Comment: Simply use a loop. Faster, safer, more readable, less stack use, better in every single way possible.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: @MrSmith42 What's wrong with asking homework questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want  to find the number within a range in an array
>
> Let's say in the range of 2 and 3

Normally a `for` loop or similar would be so much easier here

If it has to be recursive....

```
// need to have another number - r - number in range
//  r starts at zero
// 
// normally lower case for variable and capitals for things you #define
// N starts at the number of elements of a less one 
//
int within(int a[], int N, int lower, int upper, int r, int result[])
{
  if(a[0] <= upper && a[0]>= lower) {
     result[r]= a[0];
     r++;
  }
  if(N==0) {
     return r;
  } else { 
     r = within(&a[1], N-1, lower, upper, r, result);
    return r;
  }
}
```

the function will give a return value of the number of values found within the range.

The code above is recursive, but so much more complicated and fragile than a simple loop... such as the fragment below

```
  for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
    if(a[i] <= upper && a[i]>= lower) {
     result[r]= a[i];
     r++;
    }
  }
```

If it has to be recursive wihtout r...

```
// need to have another number - result[0] - number in range
//  result[0] starts at zero
// 
// normally lower case for variable and capitals for things you #define
// N starts at the number of elements of a less one 
//
int within(int a[], int N, int lower, int upper, int result[])
{
  if(a[0] <= upper && a[0]>= lower) {
     result[0]++;
     result[result[0]]= a[0];
  }
  if(N==0) {
     return result[0];
  } else { 
     result[0] = within(&a[1], N-1, lower, upper, result);
    return result[0];
  }
}
```

now result conatins

{number in range, first number in range, second number in range....}

Comment: The function uses redundant parameter r.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `r` is not redundant - it keeps track of the number of values that fall in the range between lower and upper -- if we put values into `result[]` we need to know how many values have been added to `result`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, but I spotted a mistake in my simple loop - maybe `r` is not necessary from looking at your code -- but I am not sure if your code or mine is more 'readable'

Comment: @If you are not sure then your qi\ualification is not enough high. That is all.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ok - so I did not look so carefully at the detail of your code. Now I look at it more closely it looks as if you have the parameter `m` which does the same job as my parameter `r`, though I prefer to call them variables. In the same way that my routine returns the value of `r` so you return the value of `m`  . -- BUT your code has the advantage that you allocate just enough memory for the result....:-)

Comment: @tom is it possible to define `r` inside the function, not as one of the function parameter and initialise to 0. But for each loop, the value of `r` will change back to 0.

Comment: @jwlee yes - `r` needs to be defined to 0 **before** the function is called for the first time - it is not set to zero in the function and in recursion the updated value of `r` is sent.... does this make sense?

Comment: @jwlee the problem with not sending the value of r is that r tells the function each time where to add to the result[]

Comment: @jwlee perhaps the alternative might be to use N as r, but then you would have to be able to know when the input values in a[] run out....

Comment: @jwlee - you could use `result[0]` instead of `r`.... -- if you need to remove r from the list of variables sent to the function then it could be done and I could edit, but tomorrow, not now... message me if it would help.

Comment: @tom after replacing `r` with `result[0]`, I see it only store the last data that meet the condition

Answer (score 0):

Below codes will work for you in recursive way. If you don't want to print the numbers just comment out `printf` statement inside function `printfRange`. Hope you can understand the logic :-

```
int within(int *a, int rngH, int rngL, int length)
{
  int len = length;
  static int i = 0;
  static int found = 0;
  if(len <=0 )
  {
   return i;
  }
  if (*a == rngH)
  {
   printf("%d,",*a);
   i++;
   found = 1;
   within(++a,rngH, rngL,--len);
  }
  else if(*a == rngL && found > 0)
  {
   printf("%d,",*a);
   i++;
   within(++a,rngH, rngL,--len);
  }
  else
  {
    within(++a,rngH, rngL,--len);
  }
   return i;
}

int main() {
int a[] = {4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2};

int total = within(a,3,2,6);
printf("\n");
printf("Total :%d\n",total);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function should return an array of target elements. It should not output anything.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. If you want to implement a recursive function, try to do it in the way that the recursive call happens at the end.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int find_in_range(int* out, int const *in, int length, int from, int to)
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int addon;

    if (*in >= from && *in <= to)
    {
        *out = *in;
        ++out;
        addon = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        addon = 0;
    }

    return find_in_range(out, in + 1, length - 1, from, to) + addon;
}

#define N 6

int main()
{
    int in[N] = {4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2};
    int out[N] = {0};

    int num_found = find_in_range(out, in, N, 2, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_found; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", out[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the following code as per your requirements. This is just a proof of concept code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int result[4];
static int ctr1 = 0;
static int ctr2 = 0;
void recFind(int* arr, int* key){

    if(ctr2 == 8)
        return;
    if(*arr >= key[0] && *arr <= key[1])
        result[ctr1++] = *arr;

        arr++;
        ctr2++;
        recFind(arr, key);
}
int main(){

    int arr[] = {1,3,3,6,4,6,7,8};
    int key[] = {1,4};

    recFind(arr, key);
    printf(" { ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
```

Comment: It is a bad code.  It uses global variables and magic numbers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It is merely a proof of concept and I've mentioned this above. It does uses globals and fixed sized arrays but that's the point. It isn't supposed to be inserted as it is in anywhere productive rather the questioner must understand and implement it on his own. I have just provided guidelines as to how it can be done.

Comment: It is just a bad proof of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

As it follows from the description of the assignment the function should provide two values: the number of elements that satisfy the condition and an array that contains the elements themselves.

It is evident that the array should be allocated dynamically. And it is logically consistent when the function itself returns the number of elements while the pointer to the generated array is passed by reference as an argument.

The recursive function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t get_range( const int a[], size_t n, int lower, int upper, int **out )
{
    size_t m;

    if ( n )
    {
        m = get_range( a, n - 1, lower, upper, out );

        if ( lower <= a[n-1] && a[n-1] <= upper )
        {
            int *tmp = realloc( *out, ( m + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

            if ( tmp )
            {
                tmp[m] = a[n-1];
                *out = tmp;
                ++m;
            }               
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *out = NULL;
        m = 0;
    }

    return m;
}

int main(void) 
{

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int lower = 2, high = 3;
    int *out;

    size_t n = get_range( a, N, lower, high, &out );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", out[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( out );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 3 3 2
```